# Scrolling a window with changing color buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So first I made a button class:

```
class Button:
def __init__(self, text, color_idle, y, function=''):
    # General
    self.pressed = False
    self.function_finished = False
    self.function = function

    #Rectangle
    self.button1 = pygame.Rect(0, y, 280, 24)
    self.color = color_idle

    # Text
    font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
    self.text_surface = font1.render(text, True, WHITE)
    self.text_rect = self.text_surface.get_rect(center=self.button1.center)

def draw(self):
    # Drawing The Button
    pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.button1, border_radius=3)
    # Drawing The Text
    window.blit(self.text_surface, self.text_rect)
    self.click()
    self.scrool()

def click(self):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if self.button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            self.pressed = True
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
            self.pressed = False
    if self.pressed == True:
        self.color = LIGHT_BLUE_PRESSED
        # Button Function
        if self.function != '':
            if self.function == 'unlock_every_character' and self.function_finished == False:
                unlock_every_character()
                self.function_finished = True
            if self.function == 'unlock_every_item' and self.function_finished == False:
                unlock_every_item()
                self.function_finished = True
            if self.function == 'unlock_every_animal' and self.function_finished == False:
                unlock_every_animal()
                self.function_finished = True
    if self.pressed == False:
        self.color = LIGHT_BLUE_IDLE
        if self.button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.color = LIGHT_BLUE_HOVER

def scrool(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.button == 4:  # SCROLL UP
            screen_level += 10
        if event.button == 5:  # SCROLL DOWN
            screen_level -= 10
```

The button changes color when you hover over it with a mouse or press it.
To create a button object you have to specify the button text, color (I want to have different colored buttons), the y position and the function that it activates.

```
button1 = Button('Text1', LIGHT_BLUE_IDLE, 2, 'unlock_every_character')
```

And i want to be able to scroll, so i did something like this:

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.button == 4: # SCROLL UP
        screen_level += 10
    if event.button == 5: # SCROLL DOWN
        screen_level -= 10
```

And so i add the screen_level to the button object y position:

```
screen_level = 0
button1 = Button('Text1', LIGHT_BLUE_IDLE, 2 + screen_level, 'unlock_every_character')
```

But it won't work, because i have to specify the screen_level before the loop so i can add it to the button object witch is also created before the loop. So for the scroll to work i have to create my button **inside** the loop, after the event.button check and then the scrolling works, but the **color changing brakes**, because i set the button color (LIGHT_BLUE_IDLE) while creating the button, and so because i now create my button in the loop i create it 60 times every second and so  i set it's color to LIGHT_BLUE_IDLE 60 times per second.
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, only `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events have `button` attribute, so you need to check for that before you check for button events.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 4:
```

Apart from that, there are a few problems. First is this:

```
if self.button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            self.pressed = True
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:  #<- this
            self.pressed = False
```

`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]` checks for right mouse button, so your button isn't reusable until you press it.

Second is this:

```
def scrool(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
```

You can only call `pygame.event.get()` once in your application, otherwise it will cause problems. Calling it in scroll function means that you cannot call it anywhere else, thus you don't have access to events anywhere else in your code.

You are also not updating the text surface position every frame which means only the button's rectangle will move and not the text.

Also, you don't have to compare every function as a string because you can directly pass the function itself.

This is just about coding practice but a function should be responsible for one job.

```
def draw(self):
    # Drawing The Button
    pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.button1, border_radius=3)
    # Drawing The Text
    window.blit(self.text_surface, self.text_rect)
    self.click()
    self.scrool()
```

It should not be doing that. A better way to handle this is to make a `run` function to call all of the button functions.

One last thing, it is considered better practice and more "pythonic" to check for true and false like this:

```
if self.pressed == True: #no
if self.pressed: #yes
if self.pressed == False: #no 
if not self.pressed: #yes
```

Finally, instead of trying use if statements and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` to make the button execute the function once on click, you can use events for checking for mouse press and get rid of the if statements.

Here is the code with the above mentioned improvements.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((400,350))
pygame.display.set_caption('caption')

def unlockEveryCharacter():
    print("'unlock_every_character'")

def unlockEveryItem():
    print("'unlock_every_item'")

def unlockEveryAnimal():
    print("'unlock_every_animal'")

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, color_idle, y, function=None):
        # General
        self.function = function

        #Rectangle
        self.button1 = pygame.Rect(0, y, 280, 24)
        self.color = color_idle

        # Text
        font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        self.text_surface = font1.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self.text_rect = self.text_surface.get_rect(center=self.button1.center)

    def draw(self):
        # Drawing The Button
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.button1, border_radius=3)
        # Drawing The Text
        self.text_rect = self.button1
        window.blit(self.text_surface, self.text_rect)

    def click(self, events):
        pressed = False
        
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (event.button == 1):
                    if self.button1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        pressed = True                
                        
        if pressed:
            self.color = (200, 200, 255)
            # Button Function
            if self.function is not None:
                self.function()

        if not pressed:
            self.color = (100, 100, 200)
            if self.button1.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                self.color = (50, 50, 200)

    def scrool(self, events):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 4: 
                    self.button1.y -= 10
                if event.button == 5:  # SCROLL DOWN
                    self.button1.y += 10

    def run(self, events):
        self.draw()
        self.click(events)
        self.scrool(events)
        



unlockEveryCharacterButton = Button("Unlock every character", (255, 255, 255), 10, unlockEveryCharacter)
unlockEveryItemButton = Button("Unlock every item", (255, 255, 255), 50, unlockEveryItem)
unlockEveryAnimalButton = Button("Unlock every animal", (255, 255, 255), 90, unlockEveryAnimal)

buttons = [unlockEveryCharacterButton, unlockEveryItemButton, unlockEveryAnimalButton]

running = True
while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    window.fill((190, 232, 220))

    for button in buttons:
        button.run(events)
    
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: So you said "Also, you don't have to compare every function as a string because you can directly pass the function itself." How would i be able to do that?

Comment: @Eskimo868 In the example above in line `unlockEveryCharacterButton = Button("Unlock every character", (255, 255, 255), 10, unlockEveryCharacter)`,  `unlockEveryCharacter` is a function. Notice its not being called, `()` is missing. It is just passed through as an argument and saved as `self.function` by the button class. Then it is called by the `click` function by doing `self.function()`